# Why would a Wordpress site go into maintenance mode without me doing anything?

Tags: updates, maintenance, automatic-updates

This morning, my Wordpress site went into maintenance mode without me having updated anything, and stayed there for about 10 minutes. What could have caused this? I have automatic security updates turned on, could it be that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is yes. Wordpress does go into maintenance mode when updates are are installed. You have nothing to worry about. This is default behavior.

I do know that there are sometimes issues where Wordpress gets stuck in maintenance mode after updates, but if you don't experence such issues, you are good to go :-)